# How to read and save the JSON format result that we obtained in Postman?

Tags: postman

```
{
    "message": "post created",
    "authData": {
        "user": {
            "id": 1,
            "username": "usha",
            "Password": "ushausha"
        },
        "iat": 1554617615
    }
}
```

This is the postman result that I obtained.
The user is a mock user,i.e, a const user

I want only the user part, i.e, the `id`, `username` and `password` to be read and saved separately.

Comment: how do i extract only the id,username and password from the postman output

Comment: What would you like to do with this once extracted? You could save it as a variable to use in later, in other requests or do you just want to save those things to a file?

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:
1) there is a small copy button on the right of the result section:
[image: p]
click on it and the result is copied to your clipboard.

2) At the right section of History, you can save responses for all requests you have made:
[image]